# Align css drop down menu to the center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to align my bootstrap dropdown menu to the center of parent `div`. It's left aligned by default I guess.

**The Code**

```js
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

```css
/* bootstrap dropdown hover menu*/
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #4f5d6e;
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(26, 49, 95);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1)), color-stop(10%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(29, 108, 141, 1)), color-stop(37%, rgba(41, 136, 151, 1)), color-stop(77%, rgba(39, 45, 100, 1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1)));
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a315f', endColorstr='#1a315f', GradientType=0);
}
.body-wrap {
  min-height: 700px;
}
.body-wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.body-wrap:before,
.body-wrap:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 260px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 0)));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1) 0%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a315f', endColorstr='#001a315f', GradientType=0);
}
.body-wrap:after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(26, 49, 95, 0) 0%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001a315f', endColorstr='#1a315f', GradientType=0);
}
nav {
  margin-top: 60px;
  box-shadow: 5px 4px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<!--http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-->
<div class="body-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/betdream/pen/frDqh

It look bit messy on mobile view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include this below css media query in your existing css which will solve issue it is only for mobile view.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .dropdown-menu > li > a {
            text-align : center;
        }
      .dropdown-menu{
        width : 100%;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed add this class in your css and  dropdown mennu has aligned center.

```
.dropdown-menu { text-align: center; }
```

**Demo Code**

> 'http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGBrmO'